# How to set SELINUX HTTPD User Content RW?

Tags: php-fpm, apache2, selinux, rocky-linux

I'm quite new to SELINUX, I've  simple question, I know there are `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` for /var/www/html, and read only `httpd_user_content_t`, but if I want to allow some folder to be RW for that user only, is there any `httpd_user_rw_content_t` ? Or I should use `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` context for that particular user?

Answer (score 0):

The types in SELinux do not relate to the management of users in the manner I think you believe they do.

The SELinux type for `httpd_user_content_rw_t` bears no relation to having it work against a specific user. This type is really meant for conditions whereby a user has a web document root of some kind.

Say for example in apache if you use `mod_userdir` you can have [http://website.com/~myuser](http://website.com/%7Emyuser) as a valid link.

In this case, the `httpd_user_rw_content_t` type refers to data that would exist in the path for that user dir.

Rather than consider which particular user has access, think about *where* the data is kept. In your case `/var/www/html` is considered the system path for the document root and in that position should be labelled `httpd_sys_content_rw_t`.

If you wanted to make a folder rw for a specific user only (in the traditional unix u/g/o sense) then just chown/chgrp/chmod as necessary to get the access controls you're looking to apply.

Comment: Uhm, I think you got my question wrong, take example my file permission is okay, just I want to give only that particular folder to fpm/any web based process that labelled httpd context to able to touch that folder. Can I assume that I can use `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` or I should use other context? as we know that `httpd_user_rw_content_t` doesn't exist in general. I assume selinux used to prevent some nasty thing happen, so I need it to be double protected, with selinux and normal/acl permission.

Comment: If you want this file to be writable by some external CGI process that processes SELinux type will need read/write access to the target type. You can run `sesearch -s source_type -t target_type -A` to identify that. But in general the system paths should still be typed as sys_content_rw_t.

Comment: Oh, any general system path that allowed to be written by cgi use `httpd_sys_content_rw_t` then? Hmmm. Alright. Thanks.